# Aligning ul at the right of navbar, strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align an ul at the right of my navbar, but it goes too far on the right and my list items get stacked. Any idea why and how to fix this?
I've made a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/XJvLPo) to show what's going on.

Here's my html:

```
<nav id="navbar">
  <div id="navbar-container">
    <h1><a href="#">MOTEL CAMPO</a></h1>
    <ul id="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Programme</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And the css:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "l10medium", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

nav #navbar-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

nav h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

ul#main-nav {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#main-nav li {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0.5em;
  display: inline;
}

ul#main-nav li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Also if you have any advice regarding my HTML semantics and CSS, I'd gladly take it.

Comment: You are trying to achieve a horizontal nav bar right?

Comment: Yes. I set display:inline to my <li> elements. It works when floated to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
ul#main-nav li {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Since you defined h1 as an `display: inline-block` and the li to `display: inline` you get that vertical result. Simply change it to `display: inline-block`. **Note:** This will keep your list in the order your specified.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Thanks for the note and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `float` `li` elements (with `float` you don't need to use `display: inline`), not the whole `ul`.

```
ul#main-nav li {
   width: auto;
   height: 30px;
   padding: 10px 0.5em;
   float: right;
}
```

[**CodeOpen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myNZYO)

Comment: Thanks but the <li> are inverted now. Any fix for that doesn't imply changing the html?

Answer (score 0):

I used this

`margin-left: -2em;`

and it tamed the problem.